# multiplication of all numbers (between 2 numbers) python

Tags: python, algorithm, exponent

I am solving a problem (which is extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792027/boring-factorials-in-python) problem I asked before and can be found [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BORING/))  requires me to compute the multiplication of numbers between two numbers and then compute exponentiation:

my first approach was simple:

```
    n0=n+1
    n1=n0+1
    while n1<=(p-1):
        n0=n1%p*n0%p
        n1+=1
    print  p-pow(n0,(p-2),p) 


constraints:
1 < P <= 2*10^9 , a prime number 
1 <= N <= 2*10^9
Abs(N-P) <= 1000
```

here my code computes multiplication of n(<=1000) consecutive numbers
but when constraints change to

```
0 < N < 4×10^18
1 < P < 4×10^18, a prime number
Abs(N-P) < 10^4
```

My solution is  slow for these constraints and the time limit is exceeded. I searched for various ways to improve the code. I found a wonderful algorithm which can compute factorial in  `O(loglog nM(nlogn))` time where `M` is the time complexity for multiplication of two numbers.
This algorithm first computes primes then computes exponent of primes in n! and then finally multiplies them all (you can see more on this [here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf) ). But if I implement this solution in my problem I don't think that it will help because the constraints are too big to compute all primes itself in considerable time and I only need to find atmost `10**4` multiplication of consecutive numbers. So I abandoned this idea and searched for multiplication.

I found out  that python multiplication is fast enough it uses 'Karatsuba algorithm' and it is not wise to  implement Schönhage–Strassen algorithm (as I first thought of implementing this)
unless there are at least 10,000 digits (because then only it out performs karatsuba).

And also the inbuilt `pow()` is also very fast(Line 1426 of [this file](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/mathmodule.c?revision=82221&view=markup) shows the Python code that implements math.pow, but basically it boils down to it calling the standard C library which probably has a highly optimized version of that function) to calculate exponentiation within my constraints.

Now I am unable to think of any other way to improve the time complexity of my code. Can someone help me find an optimization or a completely different and better solution with respect to the time constraints.

The problem which I am solving is [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BORING/).

Comment: When I see "number too big" and "multiplication" I think about log transform.

Comment: @muraveill why you deleted your post I just saw it (i was out for some time )and it  vanished?

Comment: Because it was wrong.

Comment: Now thinking about the log again, maybe use Stirling's formula to approximate the factorial in case the numbers are too big, since in this case the approximation will be good.

Comment: Are you sure that it's this that's taking too long in your code? 1000 multiplications (modulo p) of numbers the size you mention will take almost no time.

Comment: @PaulHankin the 1000 multiplications passed the test but with 10**4 multiplications in 5.5s its taking more than 5.5 s .So yes it's taking too long .

Comment: I'm not convinced there's not something else going on. I just did a speed check, and my not particularly fast laptop can do `10**7` multiplications of large ints modulo `2**64-1` in 2.5 seconds (in python).

Comment: @PaulHankin In my code there are two factors which can effect the coomplexity of code :1. the for loop which calculates the multiplication of n consecutive numbers 2.the `p-pow(n0,(p-2),p)` function and as the power function is highly optimized  for calculating power that leaves 1 with us and this is a reason which I think that the while loop is causing the trouble

Comment: And yes from the point of mathematics my approach is correct and the best we can do with our current understanding of maths  so its all the code implementation which affects the time  complexity of my code . also about your test  you are using modulo `2**64-1` which I think is  helping your code output these results so fast because in the problem modulo changes with each input

Comment: @PaulHankin what do you think is making the code slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple *2 speed up can come from changing the code to:

```
n0=n+1
for n1 in range(n0+1,p):
    n0 = (n0 * n1)%p
return p-pow(n0,(p-2),p)
```

This only does one modulus operation per iteration.

An additional times 10 speed up can come from precomputing the factorials.
You are multiplying by all the values from n+1 up to p-1, which is the same as multiplying by -1 down to n+1-p.  So you can precompute an array A[x] equal to product of -1*-2...*-x and use this precomputed value instead of the loop.

(Note that you need to keep this precomputed array in its full integer precision as you do not know during precomputation which prime you will be using.)

The precomputation code is:

```
t=1
A=[1]
for y in range(1,10**4+1):
    A.append(t)
    t*=-y
```

and then for each case you compute:

```
return 0 if n>=p else p-pow(A[p-n]%p,(p-2),p)
```

Comment: Ya that's what I was looking for .Thank you very much @Peter de Rivaz for your help.You are absolutely correct

Comment: from where did you found out that  'all the values from n+1 up to p-1, which is the same as multiplying by -1 down to n+1-p'  .I mean this is right but from where did you learn about this property?

Comment: All I thought was what happens if I subtracted p from each number.  n+1 changes to n+1-p, p-1 changes to -1.  As you are doing the computation modulo p, this clearly doesn't change the result, and now the pattern became easy to spot.

Comment: Wow! great you thought that much, and with your this thought my code finished in the shortest time possible with the online judge.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) says that for big `N` you can approximate `N!` with logs, with are more tractable numbers for a computer:

```
N! % p =~ exp((N* ln(N) - N)) % p
```

For small numbers, keep the factorial for more precision.